# show alert dialog on specific date store in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have database file in which date is stored in date column 
   date
01/02/2017

i want to show alert dialog if current date matches with database date 01/02/2017

alert dialog with edit text to get something input

i have below code ,
code has no error but unable to display the alert dialog ,
can any one help??

```
Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getBaseContext());
//the above code will give the current date   

String dbdate = databaseHelper.inserteddate(); //dbdate stored date from database 

 if (dateFormat.equals(dbdate)) // compare current date with db date
{
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alert.setTitle("new date");
            alert.setMessage("enter new date");
            final EditText editText = new EditText(context);
            alert.setView(editText);

            alert.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String s = editText.getEditableText().toString();
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }
```

Comment: `dateFormat.equals(dbdate)` wrong, you need to convert the `dbdate` to a `Date` object and then you can compare it with your `other Date` object.

Comment: you can use else for checking

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition while checking dbdate and dateFormat resolve to false. They are both of two different types and will of course fail a comparison.

dbdata is of type String while dateFormat is of type DateFormat. I would recommend converting them both to a type which can be compared with each other before doing the comparison.